# Using random letters to pair into words from a txt.file in Python

Tags: python

I was hoping to get some guidance through my assignment, I'm completely new to programming and have no experience whatsoever.

Assignment: We are given a txt.file containing an amount of actual words and my assignment is to write a program that asks the user for a set between 4 - 9 random letters to input. Make the program run these random letters through the txt.file and find all the words that it can create with the words the user put in. It then has to write out all the words it can find containing all the letters the user typed in, print it out in a line in alphabetical order. Afterwards it has to print out how many words contain all the 9 letters the user has put in as a list.

If my explanation is messy please tell me and I will try to explain better for you. Im not looking for anyone to solve the assignment for me, I just want some proper guidance on what I can do to proceed to the next step because right now it just feels like a dead end.

This is my code so far:

```
import os
chars = []

nine = input("Nians bokstäver: ")

lenght = len(nine)
#print(lenght) #Denna ska tas bort senare

while (lenght < 4) or (lenght > 9):
    lenght = len(nine)
    print("Fel antal, försök igen!")
    nine = input("Nians bokstäver: ")

if (lenght >= 4) and (lenght <= 9):
    lenght = len(nine)
    chars.append(nine)

file = open("/Users/************/Desktop/Programmering 1/Inlämningsuppgift/ny_svenskaord.txt", "r")

while file:
    line = file.readline()
    print(line)
    if line == "":
        break
```

Thank you,

Artin

Comment: This site is for specific programming questions only, not for general guidance.

Comment: Try to break down your task into much simpler parts. For example: instead of: "and find all the words that it can create with the words the user put in" make one specific question (or better first search if there is already one -> "how to to check if string only contains specific characters"

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you are building an Anagram solver. There are a few ways you can go about this. Due to it being a homework assignment I won't give any actual answers but some routes to look into.

The pythonic way to do it is using the builtin method `string.rfind()` where `string` is one word from your target file. [Python Docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.rfind)

The most robust way would be to use [Regex](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_expression) to find the characters and sequence, but involves learning an entirely new language.[Python Docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html?highlight=regular%20expressions#module-re).

The easiest way for a programming beginner is also the ugliest way but it works with string slices and loops to iterate over each letter in the input, grab a single line from from the file using `file.readline()` then splitting it into its characters and comparing the two. Might looks something like

```
...
def Anagram(input, filename):

    with open(filename, 'r') as target:  # opens the file at the file path given in file name
        word = target.readline()  # reads one line of the file
        while word:  # While word is defined (has a value), loop!
            hit_list = [0]  # unfortunate naming, list of words the input compares too and a counter at index[0]
            for i in len(input):  # for letter in input
                hits = 0  # If a letter is the same as the string, add one
                '''
                Comparison code goes here
                '''
                if hits == len(word):  # if you have the same amount of hits as letters in the word its an anagram.
                    hit_list[1] = hit_list[1] + 1  # adds one to the counter
                    hit_list.append(word)  # adds the word at the end of the list
            word = target.readline()  # reads a new line from the file
    return hit_list  # returns the list you made
```

The above example has huge holes and problems but would work in a very narrow set of circumstances. Some of the issues include the fact that its never checked that the input is actually a letter, that the file contains letters, that the file uses one word per line, that there are no line end character, ect ect. Things to think about when writing or reading other peoples code.

Have fun with the project Artin!

Comment: Many thanks Dylan for your guidance, it means a lot and ill try to do my best of solving the assignment. Have a nice day!